# How Do I modify This Circuit using a push button?

Tags: clock

This circuit below is for a completely functional digital clock.
However, I would like to add a `2 push button` that can `modify` the `hours and minutes` on the seven segment displays of this clock. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a question here somewhere?

Comment: What is your actual question? Where are you stuck? Can you explain how this circuit works as-is? What do those 2 existing push-buttons do?

Comment: These two buttons do nothing, This circuit is a Digital Clock Circuit That uses 7490 Counter and a functional generator to work as a digital clock.

Comment: Throw that circuit away and use an Arduino comes to mind....

Comment: I want to add 2 push buttons, which can set the current time in this clock. ( current time on the seven segment)

Comment: BUt you need to explain in the question what the new buttons are supposed to do..... YOur question is meaningless at present.

Comment: Do you want to add two more buttons in addition to two buttons you already have?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev , ignore these two buttons. consider them as a single line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest and typical solution is to use a STDT push button on the clock line to the appropriate counters to switch from the ripple clock to the raw clock.

When pressed that particular stage will count faster.

[image]

Something like this....

[image]

**NOTE:** I added a little debounce to that signal. If you need too much for the switch to work right without interfering with the ripple clock you may need a different circuit to make the switch input synchronous to the main clock signal.

Comment: Umm.. I do get what you are saying but I am unable to implement. Can you do that roughly on my circuit diagram please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MuhammadYasirJaved I could if I could read it... Try posting a higher resolution image.

Comment: Sure Just a second, I will zoom into that part and post it.

Comment: Please recheck the post :) @Trevor

Comment: @MuhammadYasirJaved updated answer with sketch

Comment: @MuhammadYasirJaved though what you had should have worked sort of.... button bouncing is a problem with both though.

Comment: Oh My God Man. You are a savior! God bless you!!! Thanks Everyone <3

Comment: Its completely elegant :D

Comment: Can I ask one final thing also ?

Comment: @MuhammadYasirJaved YOu just did.....

Comment: hehe, i just wanted to add a alarm too, where we can set the time and that time the alarm triggers for a bit and then shuts off.

Comment: @MuhammadYasirJaved oh wow.. that's way more complicated than I can answer here. If you need that functionality you need to redesign it a lot. Use a standard real time clock chip, or a micro with an RTC built in.

Comment: Alright Man, I do appreciate your efforts for helping me with such detail and patience. :) I will think about the alarm later. :) Thanks